# Error with 'import' statement without .js extension using npm module with Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ckeditor, laravel-mix

I'm using CKEditor 5 in a Laravel project, getting it from a CDN, so initially I have not needed to run npm. But now I need an alignment plugin, so I used Laravel Mix to run npm install, and then copy the plugin to public folder. Like this:

```js
mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/@ckeditor', 'public/@ckeditor');
```

In my code, I tried to import it:

```
import Alignment from '/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment.js';
```

So it threw this error in console

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I solved it by auto replacing all **@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src** references in the plugin with **/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src**

But now, it's throwing these import errors, and it's because of the lack of *.js* extension inside the plugin codes when importing

> alignment.js:10 GET http://localhost:8000/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> alignment.js:12 GET http://localhost:8000/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignmentediting net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> alignment.js:13 GET http://localhost:8000/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignmentui net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

My question is if there is some tool to add the extension in the end of these import statements, or if there is an easier way to use this npm module without running Node.js as I'm a total noob with *npm*.