# laravel set up ckeditor/ckeditor5-export-pdf

Tags: laravel, ckeditor5

I try to set up plugin ckeditor/ckeditor5-export-pdf on my Laravel App But I cant do this. I still get issues like: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-export-pdf/src/exportpdf". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I did all steps as in docs: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/export-pdf.html#configuration   But when I try use import ExportPdf from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-export-pdf/src/exportpdf'; I get the error like above. Please help. Maybe some have stuck on this issue before

````
        import ExportPdf from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-export-pdf/src/exportpdf';

        console.log(ExportPdf);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /*function ExportPdf(editor) {
                editor.execute('exportPdf');
            }*/

            function SimpleUploadAdapter(editor) {
                editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = function(loader) {
                    return {
                        upload: function() {
                            return loader.file
                                .then(function (file) {
                                    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                                        // Init request
                                        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                        xhr.open('POST', '/admin/instructions/ckmedia', true);
                                        xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', window._token);
                                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                                        xhr.responseType = 'json';

                                        // Init listeners
                                        var genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${ file.name }.`;
                                        xhr.addEventListener('error', function() { reject(genericErrorText) });
                                        xhr.addEventListener('abort', function() { reject() });
                                        xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
                                            var response = xhr.response;

                                            if (!response || xhr.status !== 201) {
                                                return reject(response && response.message ? `${genericErrorText}\n${xhr.status} ${response.message}` : `${genericErrorText}\n ${xhr.status} ${xhr.statusText}`);
                                            }

                                            $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="ck-media[]" value="' + response.id + '">');

                                            resolve({ default: response.url });
                                        });

                                        if (xhr.upload) {
                                            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                                                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                                    loader.uploadTotal = e.total;
                                                    loader.uploaded = e.loaded;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }

                                        // Send request
                                        var data = new FormData();
                                        data.append('upload', file);
                                        data.append('crud_id', {{ $instruction->id ?? 0 }});
                                        xhr.send(data);
                                    });
                                })
                        }
                    };
                }
            }

            var allEditors = document.querySelectorAll('.ckeditor');
            for (var i = 0; i < allEditors.length; ++i) {
                ClassicEditor.create(
                    allEditors[i], {
                        extraPlugins: [SimpleUploadAdapter, /*ExportPdf*/],
                        /*toolbar: [
                            'exportPdf', '|',
                        ],
                        exportPdf: {
                            stylesheets: [
                                './path/to/fonts.css',
                                'EDITOR_STYLES',
                                './path/to/style.css'
                            ],
                            fileName: 'my-file.pdf',
                            converterOptions: {
                                format: 'A4',
                                margin_top: '20mm',
                                margin_bottom: '20mm',
                                margin_right: '12mm',
                                margin_left: '12mm',
                                page_orientation: 'portrait'
                            }
                        }*/
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    </script>```
````

Comment: How do you add ckeditor in your project??

Comment: I tried add with CDN and with Zip download The same result   Like in docs https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/installation.html

I even tried as in this advice:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046216/error-with-import-statement-without-js-extension-using-npm-module-with-larave

Comment: Now I stoped on this variant (ZIP download) :
1. In main blade file i set: <script src="/ckeditor5-build-classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
2. In webpack.mix.js i set: mix.copyDirectory('resources/ckeditor5-build-classic', 'public/ckeditor5-build-classic');
3. In edit.blade.php (in this file I try to use Export to PDF) -> code of this file see above ( add to body of question)

Comment: This is your exact location?? `<script src="/ckeditor5-build-classic/ckeditor.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ Builded what I want and setup it on my App